# How to get x value from y array

Tags: python, data-extraction

I've an [y] array of ~10k elements generating a square wave plot.
I'd like to extract the x value around y=0.
Do you know how to do that?

```
data = np.array(value,dtype=float)  
length= len(data)
newarr = np.array_split(data, 20)
y = newarr
x=len(y)
```

Comment: You need to explain how the data in the array is organized. As written, it's too vague.

Comment: Sorry, I just added part of the code. I split my array into 20 sub-arrays so now I get overlapped curves. I'd need to get x value when y=0.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of what you are trying to achieve? It is near impossible to answer this question without knowing what your input data looks like and what your expected output looks like.

Comment: Do you know that there is one and only one entry in y that is equal to zero? And is it really equal to zero, or is it the value closest to zero you are after? In other words, what does y look like?

Comment: I'm plotting an eye pattern of a NRZ signal. I just have the amplitude (y) but I'd need to know at what time (x-axis) the amplitude is zero. So basically, I'd need to exctract the x value every time the y crosses the zero. Don't know if it's more clear now.

Comment: Is this just "Find all values of `x` where `data[x] == 0` or where `data[x]` and `data[x+1]` have opposite sign"?